# How to set resource when creating OAuth service in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

In Postman, I have my GET request set up to where I can get the correct access key using grant_type, client_id, client_secret, and resource in my request body.

[image]

I'm trying to get this working in Google App Script, however there does not appear to be a setResource function. I've looked through the documentation and could not find an alternative. Is it possible to somehow set the resource to get the proper access key with Google App Script OAuth2?
https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/dist/OAuth2.gs

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an additional parameter for constructing the authorization URL by using [`.setParam()`](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/ecd68b2ee4eee2f8dcee143c2393d2f09427fa46/src/Service.js#L242).

```
.setParam('resource', 'https://storage.azure.com/')
```